# Sitetarget folder suddenly shows up in my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

So my website is working fine (for a long time)

here's the link to my website:
https://traderhub.id/

but yesterday my client call me, they said they found some articles that they never create before

here's the example:

https://traderhub.id/Clothes,-Shoes-Accessories-198291/

https://traderhub.id/Activewear-198291/

https://traderhub.id/Activewear-Tops-198291/

https://traderhub.id/category/covid-19/

(And many more)

When i tried to check my CPanel suddenly there's a folder called sitetarget there
[image: Site Target]

and this the content of that file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
 <url>
         <loc>http://traderhub.id</loc> 
         <lastmod>2020-06-03T19:48:33-05:00</lastmod> 
         <changefreq>always</changefreq> 
         <priority>1.0</priority> 
         </url>
         <url>
                 <loc>http://traderhub.id/Baby-Baths/Comfort-Seat-Splash-&amp;-Play/104/</loc> 
                 <lastmod>2020-06-03T19:48:33-05:00</lastmod>   
                 <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
                 <priority>0.9</priority> 
                 </url>
                 <url>
                 <loc>http://traderhub.id/Bath-Toys/Toy-Mesh-Net-Storage-Bag-Organizer/198/</loc> 
                 <lastmod>2020-06-03T19:48:33-05:00</lastmod>   
                 <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
                 <priority>0.9</priority> 
                 </url>
                 <url>
                 <loc>http://traderhub.id/Bath-Toys/Wet-&amp;039;-n&amp;039;-Stick-HOOPLA- 
                  Kids/292/</loc> 
                 <lastmod>2020-06-03T19:48:33-05:00</lastmod>   
                 <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
                 <priority>0.9</priority> 
                 </url>
                 ....
```

there's about ... 40000 line per file

I already tried to remove this file and folder from the Cpanel, but the link is still accessible

the htaccess and index.php file is not changed when i checked

is there anything i can do to remove this "articles" without using older version backup for of my website? thanks

Comment: The site has clearly been hacked, so the only sure way to completely eliminate the hacked code is to go back to the most recent clean backup, I'm afraid. Then, find the vulnerability and fix it or they will be back to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who having the same problem as me, using Wordfence plugin will help you remove the "hacked" file. [Here's the tutorial how to do it](https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/),